# What's difference between "reduce" and "scan"

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm studying RXJS and stuck with the problem: the same code with operators "reduce" and "scan" works in different ways, but I think that must return equal result.
Example below.
Please help.

```
const txtElement1 = document.getElementById('txt1');
const txtElement2 = document.getElementById('txt2');
const txtElement3 = document.getElementById('txt3');

// function return Observable
function get(array, initValue) {
  return Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    let timer = initValue;

    array.forEach(item => {
      setTimeout(() => observer.next(item), timer);
      timer += 1000;
    });
  });
}

// 1) don't work with "reduce"
var stream1$ = get(['John', 'Ann', 'Bob'])
  .reduce(function(acc, x) {
    return acc + ` ${x}`;
  }, 'first - ');

stream1$.subscribe(text => txtElement1.innerHTML = text);

// 2)  the same code, but with "scan" - working
var stream2$ = get(['John', 'Ann', 'Bob'])
  .scan(function(acc, x) {
    return acc + ` ${x}`;
  }, 'second - ');

stream2$.subscribe(text => txtElement2.innerHTML = text);

// 3)  and the simple Observable with "reduce" - working
var stream3$ = Rx.Observable.from(['John', 'Ann', 'Bob'])
  .reduce(function(acc, x) {
    return acc + ` ${x}`;
  }, 'third - ');

stream3$.subscribe(text => txtElement3.innerHTML = text);
```

Comment: If it's the same as in other languages, `scan` does the same thing as `reduce `, except it returns all the intermediate accumulators instead of just the last one. The documentation should have been able to answer this for you.

Comment: I don't think StackOverflow is only for information that can't be found anywhere else.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I did not say that they work equally. I said that I expect the same result. For example, the third example works the same way with both operators. But the first is not. The difference is only in the function "setTimeout". Unfortunately, the documentation does not say anything about it.

Comment: `reduce` operator emits a value only when its source observable completes. Observable from the first example does not complete, that's the reason. Try adding `observer.complete()` to observable returned by `get`.

Answer (score 58):

From RxJS documentation,

> **Scan**
>
> apply a function to each item emitted by an Observable, sequentially,
> and ***emit each successive value***

[image]

> **Reduce**
>
> apply a function to each item emitted by an Observable, sequentially,
> and ***emit the final value***

[image]

**Example codes**

***Scan***

```
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
.scan(
    function (acc, x) {
        return acc + x;
    });

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('Next: ' + x); },
    function (err) { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
    function () { console.log('Completed'); });
```

For each value emitted by the Observable, scan emits corresponding output sequentially, So the Output will have 3 values for range 1 to 3, as follows

```
Next: 1
Next: 3
Next: 6
Completed
```

***Reduce***

```
var source = Rx.Observable.range(1, 3)
    .reduce(function (acc, x) {
        return acc * x;
    }, 1)

var subscription = source.subscribe(
    function (x) { console.log('Next: ' + x); },
    function (err) { console.log('Error: ' + err); },
    function () { console.log('Completed'); });
```

Reduce function reduces the values from observables to a single value (final result) and emit. So the output will be as follows,

```
Next: 6
Completed
```

Answer (score 4):

there almost the same but scan emits each iteration. and reduce just emits a final results.  i like scan when i want to actually see what reduce is doing. so sometimesi . use reduce and i cant visualize what reduce is actually doing. in this case i simple swap out reduce for scan since it will emit on each iteration. this way i can put in a log statement and see the results for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Rx.scan is continuous whereas reduce is not continuous.