# RxJs: Scan do action after scanning is complete

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've coded this straightforward observable:

```
Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
    .scan((acc, value) => [...acc, value], [])
    .do(acc => {     
        console.log(acc);
    })
    .subscribe();
```

The console output is:

```
Array(1) [1]
Array(2) [1, 2]
Array(3) [1, 2, 3]
```

I thought that `.do()` method should be performed after scan is completed. I mean, I expected a single console output:

```
Array(3) [1, 2, 3]
```

Any ideas about how to get this behaviour?

Comment: `scan` emits every intermediate accumulation object, so this is the expected behaviour. I think you're looking for `reduce`.

Comment: if you pass one value it will emit once - `Observable.of([1, 2, 3])`

Answer (score 0):

`scan` is a kind of `reduce` that emits not only the latest value, but all reductions as well. It is useful, for example, to deal with state mutations, seen as such reductions: whenever change happens, it gonna be published further and thus subscribers guaranteed to get the latest state. But in your case `reduce` is needed, since it publishes the latest reduction; as a consequence, if you accidently get into endless (infinite) stream, - the one that never completes, - you won't able to reduce it.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350806/whats-difference-between-reduce-and-scan)

and use [`reduce`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html):

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { reduce, tap } = rxjs.operators;

of(1, 2, 3).pipe(
  reduce((acc, value) => [...acc, value], []),
  tap(acc => {     
      console.log('after all the reduction is complete', acc);
  })
).subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.1/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```